# How to add Slick Slider scripts correctly to Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, slick.js

Trying this:

Default jquery scripts in `<head>`. Replace in footer:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method' );
function my_scripts_method() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery-core');
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 'jquery-core', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', false, null, true );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', false, array('jquery-core'), null, true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Ok, jquery in footer.

Then I try to add Slick Slider scripts like this:

```
function slider_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider_ini', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick-start.js', true );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slider_scripts' );
```

Slider scripts are still in `<head>`

Then i try this:

```
function slider_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slider_ini', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slick-start.js', array('slider_js'), true );
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'slider_scripts' );
```

Nope, still in `<head>`

How do I can the Slider scripts to the footer with a structure like this:

```
jquery.js
slick.js 
slick-start.js
```

?